How to create log file on a daily basis using logging module and its rotation mechanism in Python?
I am trying to implement a daily logging mechanism with a log file generated with time stamp.
The script generating this log will be run on a cron job daily basis at different timings.
I have tried this below script (Emp.py) to achieve it, however it is only generating the file as emp.log - there is no date and timestamp getting attached to it. It is expected to rotate at midnight with new file name and with automatic backup of 7 days.
What I am doing wrong here? How do I need to modify this script?
import logging
import logging.handlers
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
import os

class Employee:
    def __init__(self, id, name):
        self.name = name
        self.id = id
        self.log_path = "/usr/myself/log_dir/emp.log"
        
        # Set up a logger
        self.logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        self.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        
        # Create a TimedRotatingFileHandler
        handler = logging.handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler(self.log_path, when="midnight", interval=1, backupCount=7)
        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
        handler.setFormatter(formatter)
        
        # Add the handler to the logger
        self.logger.addHandler(handler)

    def print_name(self):
        self.logger.info("The name is {}".format(self.name))
        self.logger.info("name = %s", self.name)
    def print_error_warning(self):
        self.logger.error(f"this is error message {self.name}")
        self.logger.warning("this is warning message {}".format(self.id))
        self.logger.info(f"The id is {self.id}")

        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    emp = Employee(1, "Martin")
    emp.print_name()
    emp.print_error_warning()

My cron set up could be any of the following, most probably it will not exactly be run at midnight :
0 */2 * * * /usr/myself/python_dir/Emp.py
5  11,13,14 * * * /usr/myself/python_dir/Emp.py
10 12,13,14 * * * /usr/myself/python_dir/Emp.py


I found that it is working, it generates the log as emp.log_2024_08_24
